# Adding an xml namespaced attribute to an element with etree E-factory

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, lxml, xml.etree

I am creating an XML using the [E-Factory](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-e-factory) syntax of the `ElementMaker` package from `lxml.builder` in Python 3.7. I am required to add a namespaced attribute to an element but I can't find documentation or evidence of this feature in `ElementMaker`.

Example of target xml (the problem is generating the `gml:id` attribute):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<XMLDocument gml:id="THE_ID" xmlns:gml="some-uri">
    body data...
</XMLDocument>
```

What I have tried:

```
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker
import lxml.etree as etree

NS = ElementMaker(nsmap={'gml': 'some-uri'})
my_doc = NS.XMLDocument('body data...', **{"gml:id": "THE_ID"})
print(etree.tostring(my_doc, pretty_print=True, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True).decode('utf-8'))
```

This throws the exception:

`ValueError: Invalid attribute name 'gml:id'`

Note that changing the colon by e.g a dash (`'gml-id'`) works, but is of course not the intended result.

Answer (score 2):

Just found the solution using the syntax of ElementTree. This would be the Python code:

```
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker
import lxml.etree as etree

NS = ElementMaker(nsmap={'gml': 'some-uri'})
my_doc = NS.XMLDocument('body data...', **{"{some-uri}id": "THE_ID"})
print(etree.tostring(my_doc, pretty_print=True, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True).decode('utf-8'))
```